# Onclick Console Message Not Firing (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, console

I'm building a simple flexbox navigation, when the screen size is below 980px a mobile version of the menu shows.

I'm building the javascript to do this - does anyone know why my console.log message won't show when the mobile version of the menu is clicked?

It's driving me around the twist.

You have to reduce the window below 980px to see what i mean.

https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/eezYox?editors=1111

```js
var mobileMenuButton = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu')
var mobileMenuItems = document.querySelector('#nav-menu')


// TOGGLE MOBILE MENU
var mobileMenu = false

if (mobileMenu === false) {

  function showMobileMenu() {

    mobileMenuButton.onclick(function() {
      console.log("clicked");
    })

    mobileMenu = true
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

#main-nav {
  width: inherit;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 5% 10px 5%;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo-wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#main-nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: pink;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

#mobile-menu {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  #mobile-menu {
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #main-nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav id="main-nav">
    <div id="logo-wrapper"></div>
    <ul id="nav-menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-1"><a>Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-2"><a>About</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-3"><a>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="mobile-menu"><a>Menu</a></div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: The function you declare inside that `if` statement would have to be *called* for it  to do anything. Declaring functions in contexts like that is a bad idea however. Put the function declaration outside the `if` and then call it from inside.

Comment: also there is no Href so anchor tags are like unclickable

Comment: Hi @Pointy I tried that and it still doesn't work.  I'm not sure I know what you mean though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are few problems, You never call `showMobileMenu`function, so event is never binded to that element. `onclick` is not a function. I believe You want something like:

```
var mobileMenuButton = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu')
var mobileMenuItems = document.querySelector('#nav-menu')

// TOGGLE MOBILE MENU
var mobileMenu = false
mobileMenuButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    toggleMobileMenu();
})


function toggleMobileMenu() {
    if (mobileMenu === false) {        
        console.log("clicked");
        mobileMenu = true
    } else {
        console.log("not clicked");
        mobileMenu = false
    }
}
```